# Error when getting data from closed excel workbooks with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I’m getting an error 1004 with my code which takes data from closed workbooks in a list. The code functions as it should and retrieves the values without an issue, however it still brings up the error message. I’m probably missing something very obvious so I’d appreciate any help anyone can provide. Below is my code:

```
Sub ExecMacro4Excel()
Dim path As String
Dim workbookName As String
Dim worksheetName As String
Dim cell As String
Dim returnedValue As String
Dim lRow, x As Integer
Dim wbName As String

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR


lRow = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
path = Sheets("Front").Range("B4").Value
worksheetName = "Template"
cell = "J2"

x = 1
Do
x = x + 1
workbookName = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & x).Value

returnedValue = "'" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
  worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cell).Address(True, True, -4150)

  Sheets("Raw Data").Range("I" & x) = ExecuteExcel4Macro(returnedValue)
Loop Until x = lRow

PROC_ERR:
  MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub
```

To further clarify, below shows the location where the data is the 1row variable is located and where the data will be put:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/62nam.png
In addition here is the spreadsheet where the original data is kept and is the same for all of the files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5xUs.png
And finally, this is the error box reads: "error 1004: A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references. Verify your formulas contain a valid path, workbook, range name and cell reference".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use **xlR1C1** for the range address, you might have just missed the `=` at the beginning of **returnedValue**. You can do it more simpler (assuming `path` will not change):

```
Sub ExecMacro4Excel()
    Const worksheetName = "Template"
    Const cell = "$J$2"
    Dim path As String
    Dim workbookName As String
    'Dim worksheetName As String
    'Dim cell As String
    Dim returnedValue As String
    Dim lRow, x As Integer
    Dim wbName As String

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    path = Sheets("Front").Range("B4").Value
    If Right(path, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then path = path & Application.PathSeparator

    lRow = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        
    For x = 2 To lRow
        workbookName = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("C" & x).Value            
        returnedValue = "='" & path & "[" & workbookName & "]" & _
            worksheetName & "'!" & Range(cell).Address            
        Sheets("Raw Data").Range("I" & x).Formula = returnedValue
    Next

PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I've managed to solve the problem which wasn't due to the code, and I've incorperated your better version of my code. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue myself. The problem was that the list of file names was copied from another list and pasted in. The way I coded it the area selected wasn't done by finding the last row and copying only that section, instead it copied a finite number of cells, which included the data AND blank cells. So as the files were accessed the code worked fine, but when it came to the one following which had a blank cell it caused an error to occur.